Django static files doesn't work on smartphones
I am using the Django framework to build my web app and have deployed it using ngrok.
Why can't my phone access the static images in the template when visiting the ngrok URL, but my computer can?
My template
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="{% static 'img/hero-img-1.png' %}">
    </body>
</html>


My setting.py
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-@p&wu2ht6d&50!yox%%#k*i(8*q(yc(3qyusw@uydit0hm42r&"

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '6785-123-240-57-1.ngrok-free.app',
    '127.0.0.1',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",

    'testdebug.apps.TestdebugConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "debug.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\', '/')],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        }, 
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "debug.wsgi.application"

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = "static/"
DEBUG = True

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"


My folder
enter image description here
Thank you
If I don't deploy using ngrok and just use 127.0.0.1:8000, It is works. But due to my requirements, I must deploy using ngrok.

It works on my end: https://6785-123-240-57-1.ngrok-free.app/static/img/hero-img-1.png

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The shosrt answer is it does work (works for me too, I just tested). If it's serving up in one place, then another place not resolving the paths is an issue with that device. Can you open devtools on your phone and get some more details as to what the exact problem is?

Thank for your answer, I have try to use devtools but it’s didn’t work.How to open devtools on IOS? And https://6785-123-240-57-1.ngrok-free.app/static/img/hero-img-1.png is work actually , but if I need to show more images. How to enter the URL?
